# Recursive Query with Cypher on a Neo4j Graph DB

Tags: recursion, neo4j, cypher, recursive-query

Is there a way to write recursive queries in Cypher?
I have to traverse all the paths from a set of nodes(with a label `L`) to another set of nodes`(m, n, o, ...)`. The Graph is directional and there are multiple paths like

```
> (m, n, o, p, ...) -[*]-> ({:L})
```

The recursive query has to outline this pseudo code

```
ForEach x where x HasLabel l:
    rec(x)
Def rec(node x):
    If x in (m, n, o, p):
         return
    ForEach y where y-->x:
         rec(y)
         x.prop = f(y.prop, x.prop)   
         //f(a,b) is a trivial arithmetic function with subtraction and division.
```

The solution to this need not be a recursive one. Any other solution will be appreciated.

---

EDIT:
Before the query begins, `m.prop, n.prop, ..` are set to some values as required. And all other nodes(say `x`) in the graph have their `x.prop = 0`.

There are multiple directed paths as `(m,n,o,..)-[*]->({L})`.
For every node `x` in these paths where `(m,n,o,..)-[*]->y-->x-[*]->({:L})` I need,
    `x.prop = x.prop + y.prop.`

This is a way to propagate a property from `(m,n,o)` to `({:L})`.

---

Example:

```
a-->b-->c-->d:L
    ^
    |
e-->f-->g:L
```

In the beginning, `a.prop = 1, e.prop = 2` and all other nodes have `prop` as `0` i.e. `b.prop = f.prop = c.prop = d.prop = g.prop = 0`

```
Step 1: f.prop = 2
Step 2: b.prop = 1+2 = 3
Step 3: c.prop = 3, g.prop = 2
Step 4: d.prop = 3
```

This routine is easy when defined recursively at each node `x` as
`x.prop += (y.prop + z.prop + ...)` where `y-->x, z-->x, ...`

I hope this clears up the confusion.

---

EDIT:
I wrote a query using paths before posting on stackoverflow. But, there could be a logical error or problem with foreach loop. This might help in coming up with the solution.

```
MATCH p=((u)-[*]->(v:L{}))
MATCH (x)-[]->(u)
WHERE x.id in ['m','n','o']
FOREACH(n in nodes(p) | set n.marked=x.marked+n.marked)
```

---

EDIT: Caught the problem with my query. The above query sets the property correctly for the nodes in the end labelled as 'L'. But, does not set the property correctly for the nodes in the path in scenarios like this

```
    c-->d:L
    ^   
    |
a-->b-->e:L
```

If my query starts with `a.marked=1`, after finishing it sets `b.marked=2`. Because `b` is in two paths leading to nodes with label '`L`'. But, `b.marked=1` is the expected value as it is connected to node, `a` via one path only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I'm doing the right thing.  A description of what you're trying to do in English might be helpful.  Still, here's a stab at it:

```
MATCH path=(start)-[*0..5]-(:L)
WHERE start.prop > 0
WITH nodes(path)[-2] AS x, y
SET y.prop = (y.prop + x.prop)
```

Because we're doing a variable path match, `path` will find every path from `l` to every node connected to it in an inbound manner.  We don't include any `y` values which are in our exclude list.  Then for each `path` found we take the second to last (`x`) and the last (`y`) and do our calculation and our `SET`.

Hope that's helpful!

**EDIT**: From your examples it seems like you want to match on relationships regardless of direction (it seemed like you just wanted to match paths incoming to the start point(s)).  I've remove the less than (`<`) so that the path matches bi-directionally.  I've also made some other changes now that I understand the problem better and I think it might help.

Also keep in mind that I added a limit on the size of the variable path.  You may want to adjust this to be bigger (or not limited at all) depending on the size/topology of your graph.  Also note that `-[*]-` matches (I think) from a path of length one to an infinite path length.  So if you adapt my solution you'll probably want to use `-[0..]` because the option of a zero path length match in crucial to it.

Comment: I wrote a query using paths. But, it did not work as expected. There could be some other logical mistake.
Here it its.
`MATCH p=((u)-[*]->(v:Kern{}))
MATCH (x)-[]->(u)
WHERE x.id in ['m','n','o']
FOREACH(n in nodes(p) | set n.marked=x.marked+n.marked)`

Comment: BTW, your query is not what I expected. I edited my question and added some details. I hope I will be clear now. I also added my solution with paths which has a problem. I hope it will help you in understanding my problem.